# Auto complete when using Play Framework 2.2.3 and IntelliJ 13.1

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm having problems with auto-completion when using Play Framework 2.2.3 and IntelliJ.

I tried to import the jar play_2.10.jar to classpath, but it didn't work.

These are the kind of error I'm facing:
When I use 
import play.data.validation.Constraints IntelliJ complains about "Cannot resolve symbol 'data'".

When I use
return redirect(routes.Application.solucoes()) IntelliJ complains about "Cannot resolve symbol 'routes'".

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you already did "play idea" (to let play initialize the correct project structure etc. for IntelliJ IDEA), you might want to add some directories to the module settings.

See the following post, it helped me a lot, getting rid of the "Cannot resolve symbol" issues in IntelliJ: [Intellij IDEA can not resolve symbol with Play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577573/intellij-idea-can-not-resolve-symbol-with-play-framework)