# Play Framework & IntelliJ - Cannot resolve symbol index/routes

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, intellij-14, playframework-2.4

I'm new to **playframework/intellij** and I have finally managed to import a play-java-intro succesfully (yey!), but when I try to edit the Application.java file, I see the error shown in the picture below "**Cannot resolve symbol index**" and "**Cannot resolve symbol routes"**.

What does this mean? **How do I get rid of these errors/warnings?**

I have tried to run the program aswell to see if it works, and the project works. This means that the errors are showing false.

Also, how do I refresh the project in IntelliJ? I once managed to do this, but that was after a popup came in the topright corner. I have never managed to find the refresh button after that. Just a "**Synchronize Project**", which does nothing.

[image: Error in IntelliJ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve symbol routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063562/cannot-resolve-symbol-routes)

Comment: I had the similar problem - [please see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577573/intellij-idea-can-not-resolve-symbol-with-play-framework/47632950#47632950).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as following:

1- In intelliJ navigate to Project Structure > Modules

2- In the sources tab find target > scala_2.11 > src_managed > main and click on it.

[image: Project Structure]

3- Mark in as 'Sources' by clicking the button on top of browsing pane.

4- Click OK

That should be it.

Comment: EDIT: i have scala 2.10... why is it not 2.11 at me?

Comment: @user2621292 Have you set your scalaVersion property in build.sbt file to a correct value? Try this in your build.sbt: `scalaVersion := "2.11.2"`

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and I Have updated my IntelliJ to version 2017.3 and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij 2022 try running `sbt run` once and hit the url (e.g localhost:9000) .

Tested on Play official [samples](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples.)