# Can not resolve symbol "routes" in play 2.5.1

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to follow up the Play framework tutorial [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaRouting). It does not work for the reverse routing part. You can see the red line IntelliJ is showing:

[image]

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij IDEA can not resolve symbol with Play framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577573/intellij-idea-can-not-resolve-symbol-with-play-framework)